# Rails: url_encode while also encoding `.` (or: html_safe for url_encoding)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filepath, url-encoding

I am working on a Rails application that displays the contents of a Git repository.

Because I want to make the routes as nice-looking (and Search-Engine friendly) as possible, I want to use the following format:
`website.com/repository_name/branch/preview_file/:file_path`

So I have a route set up for my RepositoriesController that looks like

```
member do
  get 'preview_file/:file_path', action: :preview_file, as: :preview_file
end
```

This works fine for (most) directories, but when passing any file_path that contains a period (an example: `fancy_image.png`), it goes wrong, as Rails then tries to serve content in the format designated by the file path.

Therefore, I want to [urlencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) all periods (`.`) that exist within a filename to `%2E`.

This creates the following problem, however: When constructing a path in the view using e.g. `preview_file_repository_path(@repository,file_path: file_path)`, the result is again escaped(Changing the `%` to `%25`) by the path expanding helper.

So where I want `branch/preview_file/fancy_image.png` to turn into  `branch/preview_file/fancy_image%2Epng` it turns into `branch/preview_file/fancy_image%252Epng`

Now, I could maybe overwrite the default ERB `url_encode` method, but that seems like a very monkey-patchey idea that might break other things.

Is there a way to tell Rails that a certain value does not need to be url_encoded again? (Something similar to html_safe, but then for urlencoding?)

Or if not, how to solve this problem then?

Comment: Another way to fix this problem might be to override Rails' default way to treat a period in an URL as a delimiter of path and format.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is possible to pass a `format: false` flag to a route in the `config/routes.rb` file. So my earlier example:

```
member do
  get 'preview_file/:file_path', action: :preview_file, as: :preview_file
end
```

turns into

```
member do
  get 'preview_file/:file_path', action: :preview_file, as: :preview_file, format: false
end
```

This ensures that Rails does no longer try to parse the format from splitting the URL at a period, so this fixes my problem.